# C# Console application wont run

Tags: c#, console-application, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

Im trying to change my application to a console application. I want it to work so that if one parameter is passed method 1 is executed and if no parameter is passed method 2 is executed.

From the code I have, when I try run it nothing happens.

Here is my main code:

```
[STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run();

        RunTestCases runTestCases = new RunTestCases();
        DataIntegration dataIntegration = new DataIntegration();



        if (args != null)
        {           
            runTestCases.RunTestCaseForSelectedField(args);
        }
        else
        {
            runTestCases.RunTestCaseForAllFields();
        }

    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Application.Run` starts a message loop, which remains until your app is closed (receives quit message). Hence nothing after `Application.Run()` is executed until that quit message.

The question is if you really need those lines referring to Application. If you don't have a Window, chances are, a message loop is superfluous. The message loop could be necessary if you want to act on windows messages. However, then you would run this loop in a seperate thread.

Comment: I tried removing the Application lines, no change. When I debug args is always null?

Comment: That's a different thing than "nothing happens". Also, `args` should never be null, it's a valid array. However, it may be either an empty array or of length 1 (if it has 1 parameter). When debugging you should add parameters through Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You would find out the real problem if you debug it, as in put a breakpoint in the `args != null` line and see **exactly** what's inside `args`.

However, it's probably because `args` is never null, so make it:

```
if (args.Any())
```

(Edit: **JeffRSon** also caught another thing wrong with your code, so his answer is right too, however, you'll hit the `args` problem I describe once you fix it the original problem. So I'll keep my answer here too.

When launching a console app with no parameters, the `args` will be an empty array, **not** a null value)

Comment: This would not make it to where nothing would happen, though. It would just make it to where the first method would always be called.

Comment: @NickFreeman, very true, then I'd ask the OP to clarify what he intends to happen. If one parameter is only required, why is he passing in the entire array into `RunTestCaseForSelectedField`? Does he want a different method run when there are two or more parameters passed in? I guess my original point is that the code wouldn't be run even in the first place because `args` is never going to be null.

Comment: I didn't realize I was passing in the whole array, beginners mistake

Answer (score 0):

Remove first three lines in main method.
Check in project properties if the `Output type` is `Console Application`
Set entry point to your method

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to comment but one problem I see is that your first condition will always be true because args with no command line input is a zero length string array rather than a null value. You want to check to see what is in args rather than assume it is null.

Answer (score 0):

Application related code is not needed in an console application , its used only in windows applicattion(wpf) also what others told about 'args' is valid .

Answer (score 0):

```
if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            runTestCases.RunTestCaseForSelectedField(args[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            //runTestCases.RunTestCaseForAllFields();
            Console.WriteLine("No Parameter");
        }
```

This is what I have now , whenever I run it, it runs the else statement. Why arent my parameters being picked up?

Comment: Well how are the parameters being passed in? Where are you setting them?

Comment: In the command line , I had forgotten to put a placeholder in my .bat file.